Erro no next build 'Error: Failed to collect page data for'
Eu criei uma nova aplicação React NextJs mesmo sem fazer nenhuma alteração eu estou recebendo um erro no comando next build, vale no tar que o comando npm run dev funciona normalmente, mas ao fazer a build com o comando next recebo o seguinte erro:
Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully
 ✓ Linting and checking validity of types    
   Collecting page data  ...Error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/server/app-render/work-unit-async-storage.external.js'
Require stack:
- C:\workspace\ws-caxias\caxias-diary\frontend\.next\server\app\favicon.ico\route.js
...

> Build error occurred
[Error: Failed to collect page data for /favicon.ico] { type: 'Error' }

A possível solução que eu já tentei foi criar um arquivo favicon.ico na pasta public, e o erro com o favicon sumiu, mas um erro de mesma natureza surgiu só que ao invés do favicon foi com o _not-found que o erro se referiu.
